# Laravel timestamp return [object object] using eloquent

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent, datatables, timestamp

Anybody can help me why I've got an [object object] using eloquent in datatables.

If I used `DB::table('transaction')`, the timestamps data displayed normally (not an object).

here is my migration

```
$table->timestamps();
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Transaksi extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'transaction';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_transaction';

    public $fillable =[
        'id_user',
        'id_ble',
        'rssi',
        'measured_power',
        ];
    
    
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'id_user', 'id');
    }
    public function ble(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\BLE', 'id_ble', 'id_ble');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
    public function search_getList(){
        $id=Transaction::
            get()
            ->map(function($key){
                return [
                    'id_user'       => $key->id_user,
                    'name'          => $key->user->name,
                    'department'    => $key->user->id_dept,
                    'location'      => $key->ble->id_loc,
                    'rssi'          => $key->rssi,
                    'measured_power'=> $key->measured_power,
                    'updated_at'    => $key->updated_at
                ];
            });
            dd($id);
        return Datatables::of($id)->make(true);
    }
```

and here is the result if I dd($id)

[image: Text]

Please help me to find the root cause, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

format this updated at

```
 'updated_at'    => $key->updated_at->format('jS F Y h:i:s A'),
```

OR

```
'updated_at'    => $key->updated_at->toDateTimeString();
```

You can fomate this your desire format